# Using color palettes with SDL

Tags: c, sdl

I'm creating a PC port of a Gameboy Color game from scratch using SDL and C as a personal project and learning experience. The game uses palette swaps to create effects, and I'd like to be able to do the same. I've read that there are palette functions for SDL, but that they're depreciated and barely functional.

Since I can't use those, what would be the best way to emulate a palette swap in my case?

Comment: Thank you! This was written on a 3DS late at night xD

Comment: No problem, fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

I know OP is not looking for an answer any more, but this might help someone else.

The `SDL_Surface` has a `SDL_PixelFormat` which has a `SDL_Palette` where you may set the colors. Then it is just a matter of displaying the surface.

For futher reading:

http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Palette

http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated? Can you give a link to the source?

*Maybe* (untested) you can't use it directly as the output surface because of your desktop configuration but AFAIK 8-bit indexed color palette surfaces are supported by SDL, you can create one indexed offscreen surface, adjust the palette, and then blit it to the output surface.

**edit**

That's an SDL1.2 working example, sadly the gif used here doesn't have the palette converted correctly so the cycle just appear as some flash, I didn't look for any better.

Note that you can't poke directly into the surface palette, need to use `SDL_SetColors()`

The SDL2.0 add some function to handle the palette but I expect it to work (*untested*).

test.c:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

void cycle(SDL_Color *colors, int first, int ncolors) {
    int i;
    SDL_Color tmp;
    tmp = colors[first];
    for (i=first+1; i < first+ncolors; i++)
        colors[i-1] = colors[i];
    colors[i-1] = tmp;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Surface *out, *gif;
    SDL_Event event;
    int gameover = 0, i;
    int ncolors;
    SDL_Color *palette;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    out = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, 0);
    gif = IMG_Load("Grafx2.gif");
    if (gif == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"IMG_Load(): %s\n",IMG_GetError());
        goto err; /* <- evil */
    }
    printf("Bpp %d\n", gif->format->BytesPerPixel);
    printf("bpp %d\n", gif->format->BitsPerPixel);
    ncolors = gif->format->palette->ncolors;
    printf("ncolors %d\n", ncolors);
    palette = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Color)*ncolors); /* error check */
    for (i=0; i < ncolors; i++) {
        palette[i] = gif->format->palette->colors[i];
        printf("[%d] r=%d, g=%d, b=%d\n", i, palette[i].r, palette[i].g,
               palette[i].b);
    }
    while (!gameover) {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                gameover = 1;
        }
        cycle(palette, 192, 64);
        SDL_SetColors(gif, palette, 0, ncolors);
        SDL_BlitSurface(gif, NULL, out, NULL);
        SDL_UpdateRect(out, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    free(palette);
    SDL_FreeSurface(gif);
 err:
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CC = gcc

# CFLAGS += $(shell sdl-config --cflags)
# LIBS += $(shell sdl-config --libs)

CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config SDL_image --cflags)
LIBS += $(shell pkg-config SDL_image --libs)

# CFLAGS += -Wno-switch

all: Grafx2.gif test

test.o: test.c
    $(CC) -Wall -O2 $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

test: test.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

Grafx2.gif:
    wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Grafx2.gif

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f test *.o
```

Comment: Okay, so upon a second look, they don't look to be deprecated, but I did read that a lot of people have trouble with them. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Does the question author get notifications on answer edit if I don't mention it explicitly? @Velovix

Answer (score 0):

1. Use only 256 color

screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 8, SDL_HWPALETTE);
SDL_SetPalette(screen, SDL_LOGPAL|SDL_PHYSPAL, colors, 0, 256);
article post - https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlsetpalette.html

2. If all the palettes are combined to exceed 256 colors, you must use a pixel shader.

screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_FULLSCREEN);
Use Pixel Shader.
article post - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43294/creating-a-retro-style-palette-swapping-effect-in-opengl

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have long since moved on from this project (after all, the question is almost 4 years old :) ). I hope your answer helps someone else.